# my android app is saying unfortunately it has to stop

Tags: android

I am new with android, I am writing a small app, in its start stage it should play a song which I have in my raw folder under the res. There are no errors showing by the eclipse and the application runs accurately, but when I clicked the button nothing happens, in fact my app crashes and shows a message that "Unfortunately the app has to stop".
Here is my activity code:

```
package com.my.playsong;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;          
public class SongActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_song);


        final Button button1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(),R.raw.song);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
              public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    mp.start();
              }
        });
    }
}
```

Please guide me what should I do, my song is of mp3 type.
And also please guide me which one is the best website or book to learn android basics.

Comment: try this `final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(SongActivity.this,R.raw.song)` use activity context

Comment: I have tried as you said, but actually nothings improve, same message comes to me, please guide me some book I am new to android and really want to learn it.

Comment: Have you looked for errors in LogCat?

Comment: @ftp Showing us the complete error message would help.

Comment: i was wrong create method is static http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create(android.content.Context, int). I guess it should work with activity context. Suspect `NullpointerException`. post the stack trace for confirmation

Comment: Actually I am very new to android and I was watching a video on android development, and I that video I saw this code and tried it, but all in vain. My log cat is displaying some errors but I can't really understand them and don't know how to post that errors here...

Comment: @ftp you have option of exporting the log to a text file in eclipse export the same and post it here

Comment: @ftp open up the R.java file under the "gen" folder. Do you see a class called "raw" with a field called "song?" My other guess would be that the song you are trying to use doesn't exist

Comment: public static final class layout {
        public static final int activity_song=0x7f030000;
    }
    public static final class menu {
        public static final int song=0x7f080000;
    }
    public static final class raw {
        public static final int song=0x7f040000;
    }
   Tins is how my R file looks likes, it has the raw class and the song type.

Comment: Is there actually a file in the raw folder?

Comment: Yes, file is present in the raw folder and that is of mp3 type song. Kindly please guide me that how can I show my logcat errors here. I really wish to learn android programming.

Comment: Errors are ...08-16 11:55:23.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2687): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-16 11:55:23.254: E/AndroidRuntime(2687): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-16 11:55:27.053: I/Process(2687): Sending signal. PID: 2687 SIG: 9
08-16 12:00:42.134: E/MediaPlayer(2751): error (1, -2147483648)

08-16 12:00:42.444: D/MediaPlayer(2751): create failed:

08-16 12:00:42.444: D/MediaPlayer(2751): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1
08-16 12:00:42.444: D/MediaPlayer(2751): at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)

Comment: @Raghunandan, Yes, you are right it is the 'NullpointerException' a have conformed it form the debug prospective, please tell me how can I correct that error...  the debug prospective is pointing at the line mp.start();

Comment: @ftp it would help if you post the stack trace

Comment: @Raghunandan Please tell me that how can I copy that stuff and show you here..

Comment: @ftp there is a optionin eclipse to export your log to a text file. export and copy paste here

Comment: @ftp are you using an emulator by any chance? I suspect MediaPlayer doesn't work in an emulator

Comment: @krsteeve may be you are right, then please tell me how can I check that... "MediaPlayer is working with my emulator or not", I am using adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130729 in windows 7 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following under onClick if u wanna play sound on click of a button:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.song); 
mp.start(); //where song is ur sound file and MainActivity is ur java class
```

where u need to define MediaPlayer mp; like this:

```
public class Incoming extends Activity{
MediaPlayer mp;
```

Comment: `OnClickListener` is nested in `onCreate` - the declaration of `mp` is fine

Comment: mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.song); just bring this line under OnClick. It will work fine!

Comment: @ Aditya, I tried the same as you said, but result: the same message, I don't know how the person in the video is doing that...  I am following the same code but my app creates errors...

Comment: @ftp you need to post your stack trace for further assistance

Comment: console looks like:
 - PlaySong] adb is running normally.
 - PlaySong] Performing com.my.playsong.SongActivity activity launch
 - PlaySong] Automatic Target Mode: Preferred AVD 'PlaySong' is not available. Launching new emulator.
 - PlaySong] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'PlaySong'
 - Emulator] Failed to create Context 0x3005
 - Emulator] emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
 - Emulator] WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will not persist!
 - Emulator] WARNING: Cache partition already in use. Changes will not persist!